# Cumulative percentage in a barplot with multiple value per group (ggplot2)

Tags: r, ggplot2

I would like to add a cumulative percent of each group to the following barplot:

```
df %>% mutate(Taxa = fct_relevel(Taxa, 
            "Cnidaria ", "Echinodermata", "Mollusca", 
            "Bryozoa", "Porifera", "Annelida", 
            "Foraminifera", "Platyhelminthes", "Brachiopoda")) %>% ggplot(aes(x=Taxa,y=Observations,fill = Method)) +
  geom_bar(stat = "identity", width = 0.8 ,size = 1, position=position_dodge(), alpha = 0.9) +
  geom_text(aes(label=Observations), vjust=1.6, color="white", size=4, position=position_dodge(0.9)) +
  theme_bw() +
  theme(legend.background = element_rect(fill="grey95", size=0.5,
                                         linetype="solid", colour ="black"),
        axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 45, hjust=1, size = 10, face="bold"), 
        axis.text.y = element_text(size = 10, face="bold"),
        axis.title = element_text(size = 12, face="bold"),
        panel.grid.minor = element_blank())
```

[image: Barplot]

And that, with the given dataset

```
dput(df)
structure(list(Taxa = c("Cnidaria ", "Cnidaria ", "Echinodermata", 
"Echinodermata", "Mollusca", "Mollusca", "Bryozoa", "Bryozoa", 
"Porifera", "Porifera", "Annelida", "Annelida", "Foraminifera", 
"Foraminifera", "Platyhelminthes", "Platyhelminthes", "Brachiopoda", 
"Brachiopoda"), sum = c(26L, 26L, 19L, 19L, 17L, 17L, 15L, 15L, 
14L, 14L, 11L, 11L, 9L, 9L, 7L, 7L, 2L, 2L), Method = structure(c(2L, 
1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 
1L), .Label = c("BGR", "GSR"), class = "factor"), Observations = c(16L, 
10L, 10L, 9L, 11L, 6L, 12L, 3L, 11L, 3L, 8L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 
1L, 2L, 0L)), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, 
-18L))
```

Nevertheless, there is two values per group (one per method), I have the sum which encompass both methods. But it does not work because I need one value per variable. I have tried to create a a second dataframe with only one value per group by the use of a filter function (see code on below), but it does not work either.

```
df2 <- df %>% filter(Method !='BGR')
p + geom_line((aes(data = df2, x= Taxa,y=sum/sum(sum))))+
  scale_y_continuous(name = "Observations", 
    sec.axis = sec_axis(~./5, name = "Cumulative frequency", 
      labels = function(b) { paste0(round((b) * 100, 0), "%")}))
```

I think I should use the filter function inside the `geom_line` formula. But I do not know how to proceed...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `dplyr::group_by()` and then calculate the `cumsum()` and then convert to cumulative fraction **before** you plot. The key to the second axis is calculating the appropriate scalar, which in this case is just the maximum `y` value on the left axis.

```r
library(tidyverse)

d <- structure(list(Taxa = c("Cnidaria ", "Cnidaria ", "Echinodermata", 
                        "Echinodermata", "Mollusca", "Mollusca", "Bryozoa", "Bryozoa", 
                        "Porifera", "Porifera", "Annelida", "Annelida", "Foraminifera", 
                        "Foraminifera", "Platyhelminthes", "Platyhelminthes", "Brachiopoda", 
                        "Brachiopoda"), sum = c(26L, 26L, 19L, 19L, 17L, 17L, 15L, 15L, 
                                                14L, 14L, 11L, 11L, 9L, 9L, 7L, 7L, 2L, 2L), Method = structure(c(2L, 
                                                                                                                  1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 
                                                                                                                  1L), .Label = c("BGR", "GSR"), class = "factor"), Observations = c(16L, 
                                                                                                                                                                                10L, 10L, 9L, 11L, 6L, 12L, 3L, 11L, 3L, 8L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 
                                                                                                                                                                                     1L, 2L, 0L)), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                           -18L))

scalar <- max(d$Observations)

d %>% 
  mutate(Taxa = fct_relevel(Taxa, 
                               "Cnidaria ", "Echinodermata", "Mollusca", 
                               "Bryozoa", "Porifera", "Annelida", 
                               "Foraminifera", "Platyhelminthes", "Brachiopoda")) %>% 
  group_by(Method) %>% 
  mutate(cum_obs = cumsum(Observations),
         cum_obs_fract = cum_obs/sum(Observations)) %>% 
  ungroup() %>% 
  mutate(scaled_cum_obs_fract = cum_obs_fract * scalar) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x=Taxa,y=Observations,fill = Method)) +
  geom_bar(stat = "identity", width = 0.8 ,size = 1, position=position_dodge(), alpha = 0.9) +
  geom_text(aes(label=Observations), vjust=1.6, color="white", size=4, position=position_dodge(0.9)) +
  geom_line(aes(y = scaled_cum_obs_fract, color = Method, group = Method)) +
  scale_y_continuous(name = "Observations",
                     sec.axis = sec_axis(~./scalar, name = "Cumulative frequency",
                                         labels = function(b) { paste0(round((b) * 100, 0), "%")})) +
  theme_bw() +
  theme(legend.background = element_rect(fill="grey95", size=0.5,
                                         linetype="solid", colour ="black"),
        axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 45, hjust=1, size = 10, face="bold"), 
        axis.text.y = element_text(size = 10, face="bold"),
        axis.title = element_text(size = 12, face="bold"),
        panel.grid.minor = element_blank())
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2022-08-12 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Comment: Thank you, it works well. I just had to change `mutate(cum_obs = cumsum(Observations),cum_obs_fract = cum_obs/sum(Observations))` by `mutate(cum_obs = cumsum(sum),cum_obs_fract = cum_obs/sum(sum))` to obtained the total cumulative percentage of both method.